# JMS -- how it works?

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

I don't know what I must to do, if I want to send and receive message from JMS. After along time, I see, I can to run ActiveMQ server. But it's so hard. It's works under Java code?

I.e. I have this receiver and settings of Spring:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.mrchebik.receiver" />

<bean id="receiver"
      class="ru.mrchebik.receiver.service.AlertService"/>

<amq:connectionFactory id="connectionFactory"
                       brokerURL="tcp://127.0.0.1:61615"/>

<amq:queue id="exampleQueue" physicalName="example.alert.queue" />

<bean id="jmsTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"
      c:_0-ref="connectionFactory"
      p:defaultDestinationName="example.alert.queue" />

<jms:listener-container>
    <jms:listener destination="example.alert.queue"
                  ref="receiver"
                  method="retrieveExampleAlert" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

And this is sender settings of Spring:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.mrchebik.sender" />

<bean id="sender"
      class="ru.mrchebik.sender.service.AlertService"/>

<amq:connectionFactory id="connectionFactory"
                       brokerURL="tcp://127.0.0.1:61615"/>

<bean id="jmsTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"
      c:_0-ref="connectionFactory"
      p:defaultDestinationName="example.alert.queue" />
```

So, I have simple methods, whose send and receive message

receive:

```
public void retrieveExampleAlert(Example example) {
    System.out.println(example);
}
```

send:

```
@Autowired
private JmsOperations jmsOperations;

public void sendExampleAlert(Example example) {
    System.out.println("sending...");
    jmsOperations.convertAndSend(example);
    System.out.println("end");
}
```

And in the main classes, I tell the sender -- `sendExampleAlert` with object of `Example`, and receiver -- simple to create a bean.

But I have also really problem with ports and access to them. I use Mageia 5 and tried to open ports, but they don't visible from:

```
netstat -t
netstat -ntulp
```

I also catch many exceptions, i.e.:

> Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'example.alert.queue' - trying to recover. Cause: Disposed due to prior exception

(Try to use another port from open program)

> Cause: Cannot send, channel has already failed: tcp://127.0.0.1:63342

But often, I catch this exception if I want to connect not open port:

> ConnectException: Connection refused

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/

Comment: can you post the whole application logs and ActiveMQ logs ? netstat shows port 61615 is open ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dq81ZK6z
I have application log, when I try to run receiver.

netstat doesn't show, that port is open. I tried to open, but something wrong.

Comment: In a pinch, I can run activemq.

Comment: It works!! But.. I get this exception: `NoSuchMethodException: ru.mrchebik.receiver.service.Receiver.retrieveExampleAlert(ru.mrchebik.sender.model.Example)` If I use an Example from sender package, it's ok, and I get needed message. But, if I want to use this from another application, what I must to do? I can't to give indetical class, but I have duplicate from `ru.mrchebik.receiver.model.Example`